# A for loop with several if/if else conditions causing infinite loop

Tags: infinite-loop

I'm currently working on a cash register example that reads back the change to give a person. I"m not allowed to change the call to the main function drawer. I've created a function inside that begins with a decrementing for loop. Inside of that for loop I have a set of if/ if else statements to check, if it passes one of those conditions it enters and checks another set of if/if else statements. Sometimes it will not match any conditions inside the second set because the for loop i has not reached the right index.If it does match one of the second set if/if else statements it adds i++ back so that I can go back through and check that again in case that index is not empty. I don't know if it is the i++ giving me the infinite loop or if I"m not able to get back to the for loop to increment. I've tried going through it on pen and paper but I'm not seeing the error. This is the codepen if you'd rather look at it: http://codepen.io/RawleJuglal/pen/EPXvQX Function findNextChangeDenom.

```
for(i=highNumber;i>=0;i--)
 {
   if(condition)
     if(condition)
       {
         do some code
         i++ //add 
       }
     else if(condition)
       {
         do some code
         i++
       }
     else if(condition)
       {
         do some code
         i++
       }
   else if(condition)
   {}
   else
   {}
 }
```

Comment: Why all the else if blocks have i++? Then i won't decrement at all. That's why you have an infinite loop

Comment: The idea was if it did not meet the first set of if/else if statements it would not reach the second set that was doing the i++ and would continue to decrement like normal

Comment: But what if it gets through (the first set you are talking about) all the time? Maybe that's what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by incrementing i inside the loop, you make loop termination depend on the conditions which you have not shown.  If your algorithm is guaranteed to terminate, you should try hard to make this guarantee obvious by not incrementing the loop variable (and make sure each test/function call in the loop is guaranteed to terminate).

Answer (score 0):

If the first if is always true (or at least a large number of times) your variable i will never reach 0 value.

I suggest you to do something like this:

```
while(true){
            if(condition){
                //do your operations
            }else{
                 break;
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to misunderstand the construct of the if-elseif ladder. The program execution flow flows into one of the branches based on which condition is satisfied.

Checking among the available options is done before entering *any* branch. Hence, you do not need to explicitly ask it to "go back" and check another condition.

Hope this clears it!